# Divide by Zero Runtime Error while executing gitstats

Tags: git

Divide by Zero Runtime Error while executing gitstats .Please find the error screenshot below:

With a git repository which contains binary files only, it seems that getTotalLOC() yields zero and leads to a division-by-zero error:

```
File "/usr/bin/gitstats", line 1034, in create
f.write('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%d (%.2f%%)</td><td>%d (%.2f%%)</td><td>%d</td></tr>' % (ext, files, (100.0 * files) / data.getTotalFiles(), lines, (100.0 * lines) / data.getTotalLOC(), lines / files))
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: The bug has already been reported here: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3513548&group_id=203965&atid=987711 (actually your post is a copy&paste of it). It's better to continue discussion on project's site (the author was asking for an example repo)

Answer (score 0):

Error occurred when gitstats was installed with apt-get

*Download the sourcecode from*
http://repo.or.cz/w/gitstats.git/snapshot/910d179c5f116254cef7440b8511f97a99b3c277.tar.gz or from the latest [master](http://repo.or.cz/w/gitstats.git/snapshot/) and install.

**tar -xzvf gitstats-910d179c5f116254cef7440b8511f97a99b3c277.tar.gz -C .**

**cd gitstats**

**sudo make install**

*run as*

**sudo gitstats repo_path path_to_store_the_created_stats_results**